# Term for an if condition that is always true

Tags: terminology

What to call an `if` where the condition is always true, like below?

```
if (functionThatAlwaysReturnsTrue()) {
  // Some code that always runs
}
```

This is for a commit message, explaining when and why this bit of code came to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the world of logic, these are known as [tautologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

> In logic, a tautology (from the Greek word ταυτολογία) is a formula that is true in every possible interpretation.

For example, the function...

```
function isHungry() {
    return true;
}
```

Will always evaluate to true, and would be considered a **tautological function**.

Comment: So something like "tautological if" would be reasonable?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. It's easily understood if they search for the word online.